# Column value is not set for a particular date

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is the query in which we update the status of the column depending upon the date. So let's say today is 10 Aug, then we want status column to be set as 'EXP' where the value of column named expiration date 9 Aug, 8 Aug, 7 Aug (means to say that from today's date to 3 days back)

```
UPDATE ABV_TAU 
SET STATUS = 'EXP' 
WHERE STATUS IN ('N', 'P') 
  AND EXPIRATION_DATE BETWEEN TRUNC(sysdate - 3) AND TRUNC(sysdate - 1);
```

Now the issue is that status column is set as 'EXP' for the expiration date column value of 7 Aug but it is not happening for 9 Aug that is where expiration date column value of 9 Aug there the status is still 'PENDING'.

My question is: what is wrong with the above query? Please advise of any better query to achieve the task at hand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `EXPIRATION_DATE` has a time component, then the logic would fail.  It is best not to use `BETWEEN` with date/times, because such problems can cause confusion.  I would recommend writing the logic as:

```
EXPIRATION_DATE >= TRUNC(sysdate-3) AND EXPIRATION_DATE < TRUNC(sysdate)
```

This will work regardless of time components.

Comment: executed the  same in oracle developer client but is it is executing the same as script task